# Facing selection issue with drop down in Angular 4 while selecting first value

Tags: angular, dropdown

I am facing a problem in angular. I have dropdown in a application like below.

```
    <p-dropdown
        [style]="{'width':'200px'}"
        [options]="region"
        name = "costModelRegion"
        [(ngModel)]="costModelDomain.selectedRegion"
        (onChange) ="regionValueChange(costModelDomain.selectedRegion)"
        [filter]="true"
        >
    </p-dropdown>
```

The value comes from the database. The values are say 'All', 'Americas'. Now if I select 'All' the values goes into undefined into the function regionValueChange. If I select 'Americas' the value goes into 'Americas' properly and if I then again select 'All' now the value passes to regionValueChange is 'All'. But not in the first time.
It is happening to all other drop downs present in the code.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

In component.ts this is for regionValueChange:

```
 regionValueChange(selectedRegion){
    console.log('selectedRegion in component===' + selectedRegion);
    this.costModelLOVService.getZone(selectedRegion)
    .then(zone => this.zone = zone)
    .catch(err => console.error("Error getting region Value: ",err));
 }
```

for population of region value used below code:

```
    this.costModelLOVService.getRegion().subscribe(region => {
                                  console.log('in cost component', region);
                                  this.region = region});
```

hope this would help to answer.

Comment: Can you edit your question so we can see your component.ts, it would be easier to help

Comment: modified question

Comment: I think you only have to initialize costModelDomain.selectedRegion with some value

Comment: Actually the requirement is it has to populate the value directly from the database. and the first value is selected. so we can not push any blank at the top.

Comment: What is actually your values of `region` and `costModelDomain`?